# I'm unable to run all webdriver.io spec file in single browser seession

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webdriver-io, webautomation

I'm using webdriver.io run test. I also reduced maxinstances to 1, but webdriver.io still keeps creating a new browser session before each spec. Can you point out what i'm doing wrong here?

**wdio.conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
runner: 'local',
specs: [
    './specs/specs.e2e.js'
],
exclude: [
],
maxInstances: 1,

capabilities: [{

    maxInstances: 1,
    browserName: 'chrome',
    acceptInsecureCerts: true
}],

logLevel: 'info',

bail: 0,

baseUrl: 'http://localhost',

waitforTimeout: 10000,

connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,

connectionRetryCount: 3,

services: ['chromedriver'],

framework: 'mocha',

reporters: ['spec'],

mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 60000
  },
}
```

**specs.e2e.js**

```
require('../specs/spec01_login.e2e');
require('../specs/spec02_test.one.e2e');
```

**my folder directories are:**

[image]

your assistance is greatly appreciated.

PS: I did not use browser.closeWindow() in my spec files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error on my spec02_test.one.e2e.js and it was not able to find such element, and that's why it opened another browser, and did not close that browser. The code config above is good and has no issue, it works but make sure no error occurs on each spec file

Comment: Hi @SeanRay I have a similar structure & approach to run, I have masterSpec.js where I added require('./spec1.js') and required('./subfolder/spec2.js')
in this it only executes spec2.js and ignores spec1.js 
Can you please help me what I'm missing here?